# Visual Studio Code C++: Code Runner working fine in Output but not working in Terminal

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I am trying to run the following code:

```
#include <iostream(greater than sign)

using namespace std;

int main(void){

    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;

    return 0; 
}
```

When I run it through Output, it executes perfectly fine. But, I want to run it in Terminal so I can have input options. However, when I set "Code-runner: Run In Terminal" to true and try to run the code, I get this error message:

```
$ cd "c:\Users\User\Desktop\CS101\" && g++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld && "c:\Users\User\Desktop\CS101\"helloworld

bash: cd: c:\Users\User\Desktop\CS101" && g++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld && c:UsersUserDesktopCS101"helloworld: No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure what the problem is, because when I create a C file in the same folder and run it via gcc (filename).c -> ./a.exe , it also works fine. Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: For security reasons, the search path in bash does not usually include the current directory.  To run, use `./helloworld` -- note also that Windows directory separators are not valid in bash.  Use `/` instead.

Comment: Now when I type /helloworld , I get this message:
bash: /helloworld: No such file or directory

Also, for some reason my terminal in VS is /cygdrive/c/Users/User/Desktop/CS101, yet my cmd only shows C:\Users\User. Could this be the problem? I'm trying to confirm if this is the issue, but everytime I use cd to reach CS101, close my cmd, and then run it again, my cmd only shows C:\Users\User.

Thank you for your help! I really appreciate it. I've been wracking my brain on this issue all day lol.

Comment: In bash: `cd /cygdrive/c/Users/User/Desktop/CS101; ./helloworld` ...  or: `/cygdrive/c/Users/User/Desktop/CS101/helloworld`.  From windows command prompt, yes, the local directory when you open `cmd` is your user directory `C:\Users\User` by default.  From that location you can `cd Desktop\CS101` and run your program.